# Identifying overloaded operators in Visual Studio (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there any way to quickly visually identify overloaded operators in c++ using Visual Studio?

One of the big gotchas IMO in c++ is not knowing that the operator you are using is overloaded.

Is there something within Visual Studio or some third party tool which will automatically highlight or color-code overloaded operators?

Comment: If an operand is not a built-in type, then the operator is overloaded (unless the overloaded operator is really a conversion operator, which would be evil). - Don't see much of a gotcha here. So you wouldn't use the overloaded operator on principle if you could recognize it?

Comment: `operator=` can be compiler-generated and not overloaded. Sometimes you need to distinguish them.

Comment: Not really. Class types can convert to builtin types and trigger builin operators, and certain builtin operators can operate on class types while they can still be overloaded (address-of, comma-op).

Comment: @litb: Is it coincidence that the operators you named also are the ones that are constantly named as "you-better-no-overload-these"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a tool for this special use case, but for all sorts of anhanced syntax highlithing, refactoring and so on there is [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/default.asp), an add-in for Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, I don't see how this answers the question, but I guess I have to give +1 for suggesting VAX anyway.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Visual Assist really does a lot of enchanced syntax highlighting, but does not highlight overloaded operators. Correct me if I'm wrong.

If you need to do much code exploring, I suggest doing it in Eclipse+CDT. Among many other useful features it also highlights overloaded operators.

Comment: Correct, VA does not highlight overloaded operators.