# "Find all References" for operator overload in visual studio or other IDE

Tags: c++, ide, operator-overloading

Im looking at some codes (in C++) and it gets quite confusing when there is operator overloading. Is there a simpler way to find out whether "()"  or any other symbol is overloaded?

Comment: I think this is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388987/identifying-overloaded-operators-in-visual-studio-c. - If you see `MyClass x; x(n);` then it must be a call to overloaded `()`. - If you see `template <class F> void foo(F fun) { fun(); }` then it depends on the instantiation (F could be a function or a function object) and you are not supposed to care (it's an abstraction).

Comment: @UncleBens, it isn't a duplicate of it. the other question asks only about Visual Studio

Comment: @UncleBens, it could likewise have a conversion function to a function pointer or reference type which is then called by the `x(n)`. Situation isn't that clear.

Answer (score 1):

KDevelop4 can do it. `Test` has a public constructor taking an `int`, so it shows its operator+ for all but the last use of `operator+`